# Python mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.zoomed_inset_axes moving position of grey zoom lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.zoomed_inset_axes` to have a zoom plot of a primary plot.

I am not able to move the grey zoom lines(connecting ax1 to axins) so that they do not run in front of the axes of either plot. I would like it so that the zoom lines run from the **right** side of ax1 to the **left** side of axins(not the right side of axins) i.e where the red lines are which I have edited in.

It would be preferable to be able to configure any ax1 corner to connect to any axins corner. I know this is quite niche so would appreciate any help! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIO2G.png)

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

x = np.linspace(1,20,20)
y = np.zeros(20)

for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = x[i]**2

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0.05, 0.05, 0.45, 0.8])

ax1.scatter(x,y)

axins = inset_axes(ax1, width="100%", height="100%",
                   bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.0, 1, 1),
                   bbox_transform=ax1.transAxes, loc= 7, borderpad=0)
mark_inset(ax1, axins, loc1=1, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.6")

axins.set_xlim(8,12)
axins.set_ylim([50,150])
axins.scatter(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIO2G.png)

Comment: Did you search for existing questions on that topic?

Comment: Yes! I saw your very useful answer to the truncated plot and your inset locator demo which helped with the code but could not find how to change location of the lines. I will have to edit them in afterwards if I cannot find anything.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thanks so much, it's beyond me how you know inset locator so well!